# Событие при resize окна

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ребят уже битый час бьюсь, что не так со скриптом ? Собственно при разрешении меньше 992px окна браузера, должно отрабатывать событие. По клику добавляется класс. Проблема в том, что событие отрабатывает через раз. То-есть например я делаю resize окна, остановился на 768, событие отработало. Чуть передвинул браузер, все, уже не работает. Еще немного уменьшил окно, опять заработало.

https://codepen.io/brezze/pen/ERONZN

Где ошибка ?

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>

$(window).on('resize', function() {
    if ($(window).width() <= 992) {
        $('.wrap').click(function(){

            $('.item', this).toggleClass('open');

        });
    } 
}).trigger('resize');
```

Comment: в кодопене работает все как вы и описали

Comment: У вас при каждом изменении окна вешается новый обработчик событий на кнопку. Поэтому переключение `toggleClass` выполняется много раз, соответственно будет класс или не будет зависит от количества обработчиков, а именно четное их количество или не четное. Напишите `console.log("click")` внутри обработчика клика.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно понимать, что при изменении размера, `resize` событие исполняется, зачастую, не один раз, а несколько, именно поэтому у вас не получается, когда у вас проходит несколько событий `resize` при изменении ширины.

Лучше всего в `resize` определять только ширину окна, а остальной функционал вынести. Также проверку на ширину делайте после нажатия, а не перед ним.

### Ваш пример

```js
let currentWidth = $(window).width();

$(window).on('resize', function() {
  currentWidth = $(window).width();
});


$('.wrap').click(function() {
  if (currentWidth <= 992) {
    $('.item', this).toggleClass('open');
  }
});
```

```css
.item {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 10px;
}

.wrap {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.open {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```